# AWS USER in different account unable to download file from S3 but can list it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have 2 accounts, Account A has s3 bucket, and B has the User.

I can use the creds of the user and list the bucket and everything inside it
but when i try to download something it gives the below error.

`fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden`

Bucket Policy in Account A:

```
{
    "Sid": "SplunkRead",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<Account_B_ID>:root"
    },
    "Action": [
        "s3:GetBucketAcl",
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:GetObject"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::aws-controltower-logs-<Account_A_ID>-us-east-1/*",
        "arn:aws:s3:::aws-controltower-logs-<Account_A_ID>-us-east-1"
    ]
}
```

IAM user permission in AccountB

```
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
```

with resource as

```
    "Resource": [
        "*"
    ]
```

Comment: What S3 permissions does user B's IAM policies have?

Comment: That bucket policy gives permission to account B but not necessarily to a given IAM user in account B. That user will still need S3 permissions. An admin in account B would delegate permissions to the IAM user e.g. `s3:GetObject` on `arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*`.

Comment: @jarmod i have updated my question with more info,,

Comment: Are these objects KMS-encrypted? Also, run through [How do I troubleshoot 403 Access Denied errors from Amazon S3?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/).

Comment: @jarmod  they were using s3 default encryption,  so i disabled that for now.

Comment: SSE-S3 is transparent and wouldn't cause this.

Comment: Hmm, from your bucket name I'd assume these are AWS Control Tower logs. Were they written by Control Tower? Is that AWS service the owner of the logs or is account A the owner?

Comment: yes,  it is a control tower bucket, where data is coming from different accounts,  but i have also added in the put object policy
```
   "Condition": {
    "StringEquals": {
     "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
    }
   }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243692/discussion-between-ali-and-jarmod).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the user in account B does not have a policy to download the data from the bucket.

See the https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/

Your scenario is the `IAM policies and resource-based bucket policies`

Comment: i have already gone through and applied this, no dough